# Got the current rate from rating control in gridview

Tags: asp.net, ajax, gridview

I want to have my current rat from a grid view for each records and save it in my database.
But i can't call it like other controls in grid view. How can i save rates for each row in grid view?
this is the ID of my record in my table in database:

```
 int idx = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

    idx = idx - (GridView2.PageSize * GridView2.PageIndex);

    int ID = (int)GridView2.DataKeys[idx].Value;
```

and i need this for each row:

```
int rating = rating2.CurrentRating;
```

Html cod for gridview:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Font-Names="Tahoma" 
                Font-Size="9pt" style="margin-left: 0px" Width="799px" GridLines="None">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <div style="width: 950px">
                                <table align="center" style="width: 100%;">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="center" colspan="3">
                                            <div class="box1">
                                                <div class="box-t">
                                                    <div class="b-l">
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="b-bg" dir="rtl">
                                                        <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Font-Names="Tahoma" 
                                                            Text='<%# Eval("Title") %>'></asp:Label>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="b-r">
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="box-bg">
                                                    <div class="content">
                                                        <table style="width: 100%; height: 8px;">
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td align="right">
                                                                    <div style="padding: 15px">
                                                                        <asp:Label ID="Label10" runat="server" Font-Names="Tahoma" ForeColor="Black" 
                                                                            Text='<%# Eval("Body") %>'></asp:Label>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                    <br />
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td align="right">

                                                                    <br />

                                                                    <asp:Rating ID="Rating2" runat="server" CurrentRating="1" MaxRating="6" StarCssClass="ratingStar"
    WaitingStarCssClass="savedRatingStar" FilledStarCssClass="filledRatingStar" EmptyStarCssClass="emptyRatingStar" style="float: right;" />
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td align="right">
                                                                    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" 
                                                                        CommandArgument="<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>" Font-Names="Tahoma" 
                                                                        Font-Size="9pt" oncommand="SubmitRating" Text="&#1576;&#1607; &#1575;&#1740;&#1606; &#1605;&#1591;&#1604;&#1576; &#1575;&#1605;&#1578;&#1740;&#1575;&#1586; &#1583;&#1607;&#1740;&#1583;" />
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </table>
                                                    </div>
                                                    &nbsp;
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="box-b">
                                                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                                    <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Font-Italic="False" Font-Names="Homa" 
                                                        Text="         &#1578;&#1575;&#1585;&#1740;&#1582; &#1576;&#1575;&#1585;&#1711;&#1584;&#1575;&#1585;&#1740; :"></asp:Label>
                                                    <asp:Label ID="Label11" runat="server" Font-Names="Homa" 
                                                        Text='<%# JulianToPersianDate((DateTime)Eval("Date")) %>'></asp:Label>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="center">
                                            &nbsp;</td>
                                        <td align="center">
                                            &nbsp;</td>
                                        <td align="center">
                                            &nbsp;</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

Can any body helps me?

Comment: put your html for gridview

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through your gridview

```
foreach(GridViewRow row in GridView2.Rows)
{
    // here you'll get all rows with RowType=DataRow
    // others like Header are omitted in a foreach
}
```

and access all your columns

```
foreach(GridViewRow row in GridView2.Rows)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < GridView2.Columns.Count, i++)
    {
        //String header = GridView2.Columns[i].HeaderText;
        String cellText = row.Cells[i].Text;
    }
 }
```

similarly you can use find control in the grid view as follows

```
foreach(GridViewRow row in gv.Rows)
{
    TextBox txtTotal = row.cells[0].Controls[0].FindControl("TOTAL") as TextBox;
    string value = txtTotal.Text;

    // Do something with the textBox's value
}
```

similarly you will have to find you `Rating2` in the cell and cast it into rating control and get it's value.

Comment: i need each row individually. because each user need to vote to each record in that page. so i need some thing like bellow for rating control to solve my problem.
here is the code for a grid view inside grid view:
        ((GridView)GridView1.Rows[idx].Cells[0].FindControl("GridView2") as GridView).